# bigQuery Google Cloud how to share table with other users?

Tags: google-bigquery

I currently have a gcp account and are investigating permissions for the big query. I wonder if I can share the table with other users.

I read the related documents but could not find the answer.  (cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In BigQuery you can set access on dataset level as a lowest. Tables and views are child resources of datasets and they inherit permissions from their respective parent dataset. See more at [Access Control](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control)

If you want user to have access to specific table in dataset - the workaround is to use so called authorized views

So, you can create view on top of table of interest - you put this view to the dataset that the user has already access to - then you give that view access to dataset where you have your table of interest. you are done now. User has access to the table via view but at the same time user does not have access to the dataset where this table is ...

see more on [Creating an Authorized View in BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/share-access-views)

Answer (score 1):

In the classic UI (https://bigquery.cloud.google.com):

[image]

Also with the API: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/datasets/update

Comment: thanks. but  I want to share tables, not datasets. ^^;

Comment: This is how you sharea table: you put it in a dataset, and then you share the dataset